# C++ returning string

Tags: c++, string, char, return

Is it possible to do this

```
std::string str(const char* s)
{  
     return std::string(s);
} 

int main() {  
    char* strz = (char*)str("asd").c_str();  
}
```

Instead of:

```
int main(){  
    std::string temp = str("asd");  
    char* strz = (char*)temp.c_str();  
}
```

I know it should be `const char* strz` but I need it only within block of code(and without new/delete). After returning string from method it look for reference(if cant find it, deletes string) and then calls `c_str()`. I have a lot of char's(independent from me) and I could use second solution but it takes too much code.

Comment: Please indent your code 4 spaces instead of marking every single line as code using the inline code syntax (`\`\``)!

Comment: ^ i.e. highlight all of it and press ctrl-K or hit the code format button

Comment: Your `str` function is unneccesary. Do you have it just to shorten the code?

Comment: @Zyx2000 no, it's just illustrative, practically I'm using it to convert text between MBCS and Unicode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use your second option -

```
std::string temp = str("asd");
char* strz = (char*)temp.c_str();
```

You're possibly running into **undefined behavior**. It's illegal to modify the contents of `strz`. You'll have to use `strcpy` to get a mutable array of `char`'s. Your first isn't any better either, moreover, it's redundant, since you can directly use `string`'s constructor.

Anyway, to get a `char*` from a `string` you can do:

```
char* get(const std::string& str)
{
   char* ret = new char[str.length() + 1]();
   strcpy(ret,str.c_str());
   return ret;
}
```

You'll have to `delete[]` the memory yourself when you're done with it.

Comment: I need to use this cast only temporarily(not even writeable), later it is copied(but copied from char*)

Comment: @user1112008 if it's not writable, why not have a `const char*`?

Comment: As I told it's independent from me :( I could edit structure which holds it on "my side" but on "other side" it will be read as `char*`. I'm writing extension for existing application(sending is synchronous).

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem even beyond the cast from const char* to char*

```
char* strz = (char*)str("asd").c_str();
```

This creates a temporary std::string which is destroyed at the end of this line. And that invalidates the char* strz.

It sounds to me like you should just be holding on to the returned std::string rather than treating it as a temporary:

```
std::string strz = str("asd");
...
foo(strz.data()); // use strz
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess what you wanted to ask and answer it :) Feel free to ignore if i guessed wrong :)

So you have some function that returns `std::string`:

```
std::string str(...);
```

And you have some old code that uses `char*` (so old that it doesn't even declare its argument as `const char*`, even though it doesn't modify the string), which you want to use with the result:

```
int ugly_func1(char*) {...}
int ugly_func2(char*) {...}
int ugly_func3(char*) {...}

int main()
{
    std::string temp = str(...);
    char* temp1 = (char*)temp.c_str();
    ugly_func1(temp1);
    ugly_func2(temp1);
    ugly_func3(temp1);
}
```

So, no, you must use the syntax with the temp variable. You can't write this:

```
int main()
{
    char* temp = (char*)str(...).c_str();
    ugly_func1(temp);
    ugly_func2(temp);
    ugly_func3(temp);
}
```

This is illegal code (e.g. destroying the return-value of `str()` before calling `ugly_func1` on it). The nasty thing is that it may sometimes appear to work.